# Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm building/running a code with Qt 5.11. There is a QML style in the code which is as follows:

```
// Button style delegate
    Component {
        id: enabledButtonStyle
        ButtonStyle {
            padding.top: 0
            padding.bottom: 0
            padding.right: 0
            padding.left: 0
            background: Rectangle {
                implicitHeight: enableButton.height
                implicitWidth: enableButton.width
                color: {
                    if ((buttonEnabled || hoverAlways) && enabled) {
                        if (propertyButton.hovered)
                            hoveredBgColor
                        else
                            defaultBgColor
                    } else {
                        selectedBgColor
                    }
                    if (propertyButton.pressed)
                        selectedBgColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'm receiving following warning at the line `color: {`

```
Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
```

I couldn't figure out how to resolve this error. Can anybody give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `return`:

```
color: {
    if ((buttonEnabled || hoverAlways) && enabled) {
        if (propertyButton.hovered)
            return hoveredBgColor
        else
            return defaultBgColor
    } else {
        return selectedBgColor
    }
    // will never enter this line since the if else is absolute.
    /*if (propertyButton.pressed)
        return selectedBgColor*/ 
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I was not receiving such warnings with Qt 5.9