# Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor when including QtObject as styling file

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to add set of custom properties to be included by several labels on my QML. The idea is to make a style, but I keep getting these errors:

```
qrc:/TestPage.qml:18:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
qrc:/TestPage.qml:17:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
qrc:/TestPage.qml:16:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
```

I was following the thread below but did not work for me.

[Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186780/unable-to-assign-undefined-to-qcolor)

Here is my label:

```
import "Theme"

Label
{
    font.family: Theme.tfont
    font.pointSize: Theme.tpointSize
    color: Theme.tcolor
    text: "text"
}
```

and here is my Theme.qml file:

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick

QtObject
{
    readonly property string tfont: {return "Calibri"}
    readonly property real tpointSize: {return 28}
    readonly property string tcolor: {return "black"}
}
```

any ideas why it won't resolve the property?

Comment: Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html#object-type-declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/video/recorder?h=6.4) it uses a `Style.qml` to define a global theme. As Stephen Quan already said you should create a `qmldir` to define the singleton.

The important part here is to also include the `qmldir` and the `Theme.qml` in your `CMakeLists.txt` or `pro`.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
...
qt_add_qml_module(appuntitled
    URI untitled
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
        qmldir
        Theme.qml
)
...
```

---

`qmldir`

```
singleton Theme 1.0 Theme.qml
```

---

`Theme.qml`

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick

QtObject {
    readonly property string tfont: "Calibri"
    readonly property real tpointSize: 28
    readonly property string tcolor: "black"
}
```

---

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Label {
        font.family: Theme.tfont
        font.pointSize: Theme.tpointSize
        color: Theme.tcolor
        text: "text"
    }
}
```

Comment: hello @iam_peter thank you very much for your time to show me the answer. Yet, it still does not work. I think my issue is cmake. I followed your instructions but I can't get it work :( I keep getting: qrc:/main.qml:13: ReferenceError: Theme is not defined

I posted the sample project here, if it is not too much to ask, mind taking a look at and see what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

https://github.com/gmmo/qt/tree/main/module_test

Comment: Those changes fix your project https://gist.github.com/iam-peter/f658cf50725bc3f09786b7dcfa15c5e7

Comment: thank you @iam_peter, I'd never guessed that I have to commented out the qrc and this line was also a bit misterious to me "const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/module_test/main.qml"));" but it works now! thx!

Comment: I commented/removed the qrc as it was only referencing the `main.qml` which is already included by `qt_add_qml_module`.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes to your app:

- Declare `qmldir`
- Don't need `import "Theme"`
- Refactor `AppLabel`
- Don't use `return` when declaring properties declaratively

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    AppLabel { text: "text" }
}

//AppLabel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Label {
    font.family: Theme.tfont
    font.pointSize: Theme.tpointSize
    color: Theme.tcolor
}

//qmldir
singleton Theme 1.0 Theme.qml

//Theme.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
QtObject
{
    readonly property string tfont: "Calibri"
    readonly property real tpointSize: 28
    readonly property string tcolor: "black"
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABz3ichVDLTsNADLzvV1j5gC1wQr2hXpEgKj%2BwSd1g6n3UMRKhyr%2BzeTSFShV7WXlmPJox%2BRRFodTyk%2BqDoT%2Bj3cSgErk1r65BOBnI7ymlZ1chwwkUv3QNxfAV0JvemNXqTNuj5yu7m%2B6z32i%2Fz6DdO0%2FcreHtHT1aHbALmSIF3dI3LvyCjKI6cpSFG6cpWk60IzEthYZRY5gkcG%2FvZvEQOesuQxLXeAfb88Z1oVJfqg%2Bs1UzZBd0uBu4gSUwo2kGrkndhbJAvtXFMlVBxQ50RBv3V7%2BHxH9%2B5a1Gxqw%2BF6X8Ap7ad6w%3D%3D)

Comment: thank you  Stephen for your time  but I can't get it to work.  I posted the sample project online, if it is not too much to ask, mind taking a look at and see what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

https://github.com/gmmo/qt/tree/main/module_test

Comment: @gmmo your `qml.qrc` needs to have `main.qml`, `Theme.qml` and `qmldir` in it. The problem is you only have `main.qml` and nothing else so it cannot see the other files.

Comment: that worked thx! but what is the purpose of this:

qt_add_qml_module(module_test
    URI untitled
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
        qmldir
        Theme.qml
)

If I comment his out makes no difference.